# How can get the Paypal Expresscheckout response from my page?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm new to paypal api integration, I just want to know how to get the response from paypal expresscheckout? I'm testing on sandbox at the moment.

Is is possible to send request to paypal via ajax? I saw the example it is in form submit and I don't know how to get the response programmatically.

Please help me and many thanks

Bernard

Comment: In general you can use the new API with the sandbox. You want to get the response by using the REST api method for checking a PayPal payment object. This is all in the docs

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to read the response that is being sent back.  Here is a code example in PHP using CURL to make the connection.

```
<?php

/** DoExpressCheckoutPayment NVP example; last modified 08MAY23.
 *
 *  Complete an Express Checkout transaction. 
*/

$environment = 'sandbox';   // or 'beta-sandbox' or 'live'

/**
 * Send HTTP POST Request
 *
 * @param   string  The API method name
 * @param   string  The POST Message fields in &name=value pair format
 * @return  array   Parsed HTTP Response body
 */
function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_) {
    global $environment;

    // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
    $API_UserName = urlencode('my_api_username');
    $API_Password = urlencode('my_api_password');
    $API_Signature = urlencode('my_api_signature');
    $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
    if("sandbox" === $environment || "beta-sandbox" === $environment) {
        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.$environment.paypal.com/nvp";
    }
    $version = urlencode('51.0');

    // setting the curl parameters.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    // Set the curl parameters.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
    $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

    // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

    // Get response from the server.
    $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$httpResponse) {
        exit('$methodName_ failed: '.curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
    }

    // Extract the response details.
    $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

    $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
    foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
        $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
        if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
            $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
        }
    }

    if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
        exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
    }

    return $httpParsedResponseAr;
}

/**
 * This example assumes that a token was obtained from the SetExpressCheckout API call.
 * This example also assumes that a payerID was obtained from the SetExpressCheckout API call
 * or from the GetExpressCheckoutDetails API call.
 */
// Set request-specific fields.
$payerID = urlencode("payer_id");
$token = urlencode("token");

$paymentType = urlencode("Authorization");          // or 'Sale' or 'Order'
$paymentAmount = urlencode("payment_amount");
$currencyID = urlencode("USD");                     // or other currency code ('GBP', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'CAD', 'AUD')

// Add request-specific fields to the request string.
$nvpStr = "&TOKEN=$token&PAYERID=$payerID&PAYMENTACTION=$paymentType&AMT=$paymentAmount&CURRENCYCODE=$currencyID";

// Execute the API operation; see the PPHttpPost function above.
$httpParsedResponseAr = PPHttpPost('DoExpressCheckoutPayment', $nvpStr);

if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) {
    exit('Express Checkout Payment Completed Successfully: '.print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
} else  {
    exit('DoExpressCheckoutPayment failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
}

?>
```